# Group separators in TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, numberformatter

I pass Int in to TextField together with NumberFormatter

```
private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pl")
    return numberFormatter
}

TextField(placeholder, value: self.$amount, formatter: self.numberFormatter)
```

And I expect, that TextField will include group separators, and it is, but only in initial state, later, when I change value: add and remove new digits, it works as with simple string just ignores places where separators should be.

If I use proxy

```
var amountProxy: Binding<String> {
    Binding<String>(
        get: { self.numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self.amount)) ?? "" },
        set: {
            let cleanValue = $0.replacingOccurrences(of: self.numberFormatter.groupingSeparator, with: "")
            if let value = self.numberFormatter.number(from: cleanValue) {
                self.amount = value.intValue
            }
        }
    )
}

TextField(placeholder, text: amountProxy)
```

It formats it right, but when adds a new separator, displays cursor from last position to lastPosition + numberOfSeparators

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `onEditingChanged` completion for TextField? I would suggest that when User starts editing, you can remove the formatting and let user edit the phone number. When user finishes the editing, you can show the formatted number again.

Something like this:

```
TextField(placeholder, text: $amount, onEditingChanged: { (editing) in
    if editing {
        amountBinding = amount
    } else {
        amountBinding = amount.formatted()
    }
})
```

I haven't tested the code but it is something you can modify to fit your needs. Also, you can probably have a separate binding and model variable